# Drying up nested parameters in ruby that are passed from one instance to the next many times

Tags: ruby, architecture, dry

I'm working on an app that's heavily coupled with a large third party rest api.

The urls for the api look similar to this:

```
http://somedomain.com/state/:state_id/city/:city_id/appointment/:id
http://somedomain.com/state/:state_id/city/:city_id/person/:id
```

And the models for dealing with said api look a little like this:

```
class Appointment
    SINGULAR_PATH = '/appointment'

    def person
        Person.find(state_id, city_id, person_id)
    end
end

class Person
    SINGULAR_PATH = '/person'

    def self.find(state_id, city_id, id)
        RestCall.get(state_id, city_id, SINGULAR_PATH, id)
    end

    def qualification
       Qualification.find(state_id, city_id, qualification_id)
    end
end

class Qualification
    SINGULAR_PATH = '/qualification'

    def self.find(state_id, city_id, id)
        RestCall.get(state_id, city_id, SINGULAR_PATH, id)
    end
end
```

In all rest calls I need to pass in the state_id and city_id to make up the url. There are many of these nested calls to retrieve other resources and in each instance the state_id and city_id are passed down the chain.

I had thought of using class variables and inheritance so that the base class will set the state_id and city_id and all subclasses inheriting from the base will have access but I really want to avoid this approach.

Is there a better way of avoiding having to pass down these parameters to each method?

Comment: Weird API. Why does it need all that other stuff if you have the person ID? Surely the id as a unique identifier would make city etc redundant.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean. I'm not too sure of the design decisions behind the api, I didn't have any hand in it but it's not possible to retrieve the person using the person_id alone, it requires the state_id and city_id along with it.